# Symfony Dependency injection with EntityMenager

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm

I had to call controller in service. In that manner I had created connstruct function and add parameter EntityMenager

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
```

and defined service for that controller

```
services:
  user_controller:
    class: AppBundle\Controller\UsersController
    arguments:
      ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```

when I call that service

```
$usersContainer = $this->get('user_controller');
```

in other controllers everything is fine.

But when I call self controller I get error

```
Catchable Fatal Error: 
Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Controller\UsersController::__construct()
must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given,
```

Where I making mistake?

Comment: Clear cache then try again.

Comment: I tried to clear cache but no help from that. :/

Comment: So open a built container file and check how `UsersController` is exactly instantiated

Comment: How it is defined in your routing file?

Comment: @StevanTosic May be services file has not been loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just do ugly hack and solve problem at this moment.

I had removed __construc class and add EntityManager as needed parameter to function that needs EntityManager class.

```
 public function getLoggedUserData($loggedUserId, $entityManager)
    {
        $user               = $entityManager->getRepository('...')
        $newRequests        = $entityManager->getRepository('...')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only define a Controller as service, if it is a simple class (not extending Controller).

See : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html

And particularly : 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html#alternatives-to-base-controller-methods